# Database connections not reclaimed after running app.get in a separate thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, database-connection

In console I do this:

```
Thread.new { app.get '/something' }
```

and observe active connections count in Postgres to go up and it doesn't come back down until I exit the console - a connection is lost... how come?